# Accessing id from hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I am having trouble accessing the id from a hash:

```
@categories = Category.includes(:discussions)
```

The data is returned from the above.

```
<li class="category">
<h3><%=link_to(category.title, category.title)%></h3>
<%=link_to(category.discussions.first.title, CGI::escape(category.discussions.first.title), :class => 'category_discussion_latest')%>
Most recent by <%=link_to(category.discussions.first.comments.first.user.name, category.discussions.first.comments.first.user, :class => 'category_commentby_latest')%>
<span class="category_discussiondate_latest"><%= category_date(category.discussions.first.comments.first.created_at) %></span>
Discussions: <%=category.discussions.count%>
Comments: <%=category.comments.count%>
<div class="clear"></div>
</li>
```

This is my partial that renders the list.

However you may notice on the links at the moment I simply have category.title in the url section of link_to this is because if I state:

```
<h3><%=link_to(category.title, category.id)%></h3>
```

It returns:

```
undefined method `model_name' for Fixnum:Class
```

I am new to rails and i am sure this solution is simple but I just can't see it as I have been staring at the same code for too long. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the [documentation for link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html).  Passing an integer in as the second argument is not valid.  You could pass a url (as a String) or an ActiveRecord model object, like this:

```
<h3><%=link_to category.title, category %></h3>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand things better now, however before I accept this I tried to add category but obviously as it is a hash it will not allow this as the second input? So a string is then the only option? The error I got just in case is undefined method `hash_for_category_path' for #<Module:0x00000105a87fe0>

Comment: Then you should define a route called "category".  You can see what routes you currently have by running "rake routes".  I think if you add "map.resources :categories" to routes.rb it will add the route you need (and others).